# Rudin 8.16 $\int_X \phi \circ f d\mu = \int_0^\infty \mu\{f > t \} \phi'(t)dt$ hypotheses

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Theorem 8.16 in Rudin's Real and Complex analysis states

$$\int_X \phi \circ f d\mu = \int_0^\infty \mu\{f > t \} \phi'(t)dt$$

under the conditions that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, $f,\phi \geq 0$ measurable, $\phi$ monotone, absolutely continuous on $[0,T]$ for all $T<\infty$, $\phi(0)=0$, and $\phi(t)\to \phi(\infty)$ as $t \to \infty$.

I wrote my own proof and can't figure out why the assumptions that $\phi \to \phi(\infty)$ and $\phi$ is monotone are needed. Can someone point out what I'm missing. Here's the outline:

1. Show that $(x,t) \to 1_{f(x)>t}$ is measurable.
2. $$\int_X \phi(f(x))d\mu(x)  = \int_X\int_0^{f(x)} \phi'(t)dt=\int_X\int_0^\infty 1_{f(x)>t}\phi'(t)dt d\mu(x) $$
   $$= \int_0^\infty\int_X1_{f(x)>t}\phi'(t)d\mu(x)dt= \int_0^\infty\mu\{f>t\}\phi'(t) dt$$
   where in the first equality we use that $\phi(0)=0$ and that $\phi$ is AC on $[0,f(x)]$, the second is just rewriting, the third is Fubini/Tonelli, and the fourth is evaluating $\int_X1_{f(x)>t}d\mu(x) = \mu\{f>t\}$.

Comment: I think (not sure) you'd need them to justify the use of Fubini-Tonelli. Those suppositions would mean $\phi'\geq0$ but you'd still need to show the iterated integral is finite which I don't immediately see. Also there is a typo in you last integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you justify the application of Fubini-Tonelli? You need to show that the double integral of the absolute value is finite. In Rudin's case this doesn't come up, he can just use Tonelli here. Tonelli always works, even when the integral is infinite.

In fact (for increasing $\phi$) both sides of the equation *can* be $+\infty$; this would tend to indicate that you're not going to be able to justify the application of Fubini.

(To get an example where $\phi$ is increasing and both sides are infinite: Say $\mu(X)=\infty$, $f=1$, and $\phi(1)=1$.)

Comment: Ahh, so $\phi$ monotone shows $\phi'$ has constant sign a.e. so we can apply Tonelli. What about the assumption $\phi \to \phi(\infty)$? Since $\phi$ is monotone, this certainly implies $\phi$ is essentially bounded, but as you said Tonelli works regardless. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that Rudin allows $f$ to take the value $\infty$?

Comment: @nullUser Well yes, since $f$ can take the value $\infty$ we certainly need for $\phi(\infty)$ to be defined. I tend to suspect he meant to allow the value $\phi(\infty)=\infty$.

Comment: Ahh I just figured it out, in case  $f(x) = \infty$ in the first equality we still want to say $\int_0^\infty \phi'(x) = \phi(\infty) = \phi(f(x))$.